# Generate CLIXML string from a PowerShell object without serializing to disk first

Tags: powershell, serialization, powershell-core

I have the following code which exports an object to an XML file, then reads it back in and prints it on the Information stream.

```
try{
  # Sample object
  $Person = @{
    Name = 'Bender'
    Age  = 'At least 1074'
  }
  $Person | Export-CliXml obj.xml
  
  $cliXml = Get-Content -Raw ./obj.xml
  Write-Host $cliXml
} finally {
  if( Test-Path ./obj.xml ) {
    Remove-Item -Force ./obj.xml -EV rError -EA SilentlyContinue
    if( $rError ) {
      Write-Warning "Failed to remove ./obj.xml: $($rError.Exception.Message)"
    }
    Remove-Variable -Force $rError -EA Continue
  }
}
```

There is a system-local parent session which watches its STDOUT for this output and reconstructs it to an object in its own session.

> **NOTE:** I know a local **PSRemoting** session would work, but I need this to also work on systems which **PSRemoting** has either not yet been configured or will not be.

I'd like to cut out the middleman and instead of writing the object to disk. Unfortunately,
`Import-CliXMl` and `Export-CliXml` are the only cmdlets with `CliXml` in the name, and doing some .NET documentation sleuthing has turned up nothing so far.

Is there a way to simply serialize an object to a CliXml string without writing to disk first? I've considered using `$Person | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100` but this has two issues:

1. Only captures nested objects up to 100 levels deep. This is an edge case but still a limit I'd like to avoid. I could always use another library or another format, but;
2. I want these to be reconstructed into .NET objects of the same type they were before serialization. Recreating objects with CliXml is the only way I'm aware of that this can be done.

Comment: Would this work with `[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The CliXml serializer is exposed via the [`[PSSerializer]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psserializer):

```
$Person = @{
  Name = 'Bender'
  Age  = 'At least 1074'
}

# produces the same XML ouput as `Export-CliXml $Person`
[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Person)
```

To deserialize CliXml, use the `Deserialize` method:

```
$cliXml = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Person)

$deserializedPerson = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($cliXml)
```

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70537354/45375):

- Introducing *in-memory* equivalents to the *file-based* `Export-CliXml` and `Import-CliXml` cmdlets - in the form of new `ConvertTo-CliXml` and `ConvertFrom-CliXml` cmdlets - has been green-lighted in principle, but is still awaiting implementation by the community (as of PowerShell 7.2.1) - see [GitHub issue #3898](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3898) and the associated pending, but seemingly stalled [community PR #12845](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/12845)
- Note that [`[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer.Serialize) defaults to a recursion depth of `1`, whereas `Export-CliXml` defaults to `2`; use the overload that allows specifying the recursion depth explicitly, if needed (e.g., `[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Person, 2)`)

Comment: *cough cough* it's not "awaiting implementation by the community" - [I implemented them 2½ years ago, product team then ghosted me for 11 months before auto-closing](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/10072)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear it, @Mathias; thanks for at least trying. Note that there's another community PR that attempts to implement the same, and it is still open, though seemingly also stalled (since Nov 2021) - I've added it to the answer. Note that your PR references  a different original issue, [#8311](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8311), which proposed extending `ConvertTo-Xml`, and was closed in favor of [#3898](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3898), which ended up calling for implementation of `ConvertTo/From-CliXml` (as you attempted).